# Can a unit divide a unit in a UFD?

Tags: ring-theory

My thought process so far is:

Suppose $R$ is a UFD.

Let $a, b$ be units in $R$.

$a | b$ if $b = ac$ for some $c$ in $R$

So if $c$ exists then $a | b$.

$a^{-1}b = c$ so $c$ exists.

QED.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. In an arbitrary ring, any unit divides anything. $a  | b iff. b \in (a)$ where $(a)$ is the princinpal ideal generated by a (this works at least when $R$ is commutative). Now if $a$ is a unit that means, that $(a) = R.$

Comment: Wow thanks, that's actually very obvious. Another question I have is, if we have two units a and b is it possible for there to be an x in R that divides both a and b?

Comment: If you have another question, you should post another question. Anyway, $a$ divides both $a$ and $b$.